# value too long for type character Django Factory

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, factory-boy

I have below OrderDataFactory class.

```
class OrderDataFactory(factory.django.DjangoModelFactory):

    class Meta:
        model = models.OrderData

    order = factory.SubFactory(OrderFactory)
    category = 'single',
    quantity = 75.6
    price_per_kg = 10.5
    sku = factory.SelfAttribute('crop_data.id')

    class Params:
        crop_data = factory.SubFactory(CropFactory)
```

models.py

```
class OrderData(models.Model):
    CATEGORY_CHOICES = (
        (SKUCategory.SINGLE, 'Single Sku'),
        (SKUCategory.COMBO, 'Combo Sku'),
    )
    sku = models.PositiveIntegerField(null=False, validators=[MinValueValidator(1)])
    order = models.ForeignKey(Order, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    quantity = models.FloatField()
    price_per_kg = models.FloatField()
    category = models.CharField(choices=CATEGORY_CHOICES, max_length=8)
    class Meta:
        unique_together = (('sku', 'order', 'category'),)
```

Category.py

```
class SKUCategory:
    SINGLE = 'single'
    COMBO = 'combo'
```

i am getting following error.

django.db.utils.DataError: value too long for type character varying(8)

even max length for category is 6.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a comma at the end of this line `category = 'single',`. This is defining `category` as the tuple `('single',)` which is probably being converted to the string that is 11 characters long. Remove the comma to use a string

```
category = 'single'
```

Comment: it's working but now i am unable to pass trait value to sub-factory due to cyclic dependency. is there any other way ?https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61438138/passing-trait-value-to-subfactory-django